# communication between two roscore

Tags: roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I  want to how to communicate between two roscore . in my scenario one robot wants to invoke other robot's service  but
how to communicate them through their respective roscore  so that  roscore  data can be hacked. How  to perform book keeping on roscore about topics . so that on run time communication between one to another roscore can be configured .

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/269174/communication-between-two-roscore/) by [can-43811](https://answers.ros.org/users/29359/can-43811/) on ROS Answers with karma: 101 on 2017-08-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Take a look at [multimaster_fkie](http://wiki.ros.org/multimaster_fkie).

> how to communicate them through their respective roscore so that roscore data can be hacked

I don't understand this.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-08-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0